# Runtime of binary operators with set

Tags: python, set

I am confused about the runtime of the binary operator of the set in Python.
e.g. -
`set1 | set2` Does it take the linear time as `set1 - set2` or it takes quadratic time as each element in set1 has to do bitwise or with each number of set2 or vice-versa.

I went through some websites but I am not able to find any clear view on this.
ref: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sets-in-python/

Comment: A bitwise or isn’t what `set1 | set2` does, so yeah, it’s linear in the combined size of the sets.

Comment: What does the combined size of sets mean? Do you mean O(n1 + n2)?

Comment: Yes, `a | b` is `O(len(a) + len(b))`

Comment: @Rahul: Sure, O(n1 + n2), or equivalently O(n) where n is the size of the result. Both interpretations are correct :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try out:

```
from time import time
from random import randint

size = 1
while size < 100000000:
    size *= 10
    set1 = {randint(0, size * 100) for _ in range(size)}
    set2 = {randint(0, size * 100) for _ in range(size)}
    start = time()
    diff = set1 | set2
    end = time()
    print(end - start, '-', size, '-', (end - start)/size)
```

output:

```
4.0531158447265625e-06 - 10 - 4.0531158447265624e-07
1.52587890625e-05 - 100 - 1.52587890625e-07
0.00018405914306640625 - 1000 - 1.8405914306640625e-07
0.002404928207397461 - 10000 - 2.404928207397461e-07
0.015778064727783203 - 100000 - 1.5778064727783204e-07
0.16070318222045898 - 1000000 - 1.60703182220459e-07
```

The execution time is clearly linear.

Answer (score 0):

In [Objects/setobject.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/setobject.c) in the CPython source, there is the function `set_or` which is what Python uses for `|` under the hood.

For those who can't read C, the source code can be summarized as follows:

```py
def is_any_set(o: object) -> bool:
    return isinstance(o, (set, frozenset))

def set_or(so: set, other: set) -> set:
    if not is_any_set(so) or not is_any_set(other):
        return NotImplemented
    result = so.copy()
    if so is other:
        return result
    result.update(other)
    return result
```

So lets say `n = len(so); m = len(other)`. From this you can see that it is the combination of `set.copy`, which is `O(n)`, and `set.update` which is `O(m)` (linear with regards to the second set). So the time for the whole operation is `O(n + m)`, which is linear, dependent on the size of both sets.

(Note that this is reliant on `hash(o)` being constant.)